# Bash script to import sql dumps in the correct database

Tags: bash

I'm dealing with this script since 2 days now, and I cannot figure out, how to properly set this up.

I'm using homestead laravel using vagrant for developing multiple services. It can spin up a mysql and creating databases in it by the configuration file.
When I destroy the vagrant box, it backups all databases in a separate file, and then deletes the VM.

When I want to spin it up again, it unfortunately cannot reimport the database-exports to the databases anymore. That's why I wanted to write a `simple` bash script that does that for me. It actually should really not be that hard!

Folder structure is the following:

```
.backup
└── mysql_backup
    ├── 202304041223
        ....
    └── 202304051557
        ├── service1-202304051557.sql
        ├── service2-202304051557.sql
        ├── service3-202304051557.sql
        ├── service4-202304051557.sql
        ├── ....
```

now the trick should be super easy.

1. List dirs in the `mysql_backup` folder
2. get the one with the highest number
3. list items in the folder
4. get the databasename from the dump-contents and import that said file in the database with the same name. (PS. I tried to get the name from the filename as well, but after long trying around, this seemed to work best and easiest. I'm open to ideas how to do it better!)

But unfortunately, and this is due to my lack of bash knowledge, i just cannot figure it out.

I now have the following prepared, but nr 3. and 4. of the list does not iterate over the files as I would expect it to do.

```
#!/bin/sh
dirs=()

for dir in .backup/mysql_backup/*/; do
    name=${dir#".backup/mysql_backup/"}
    name=${name%"/"}
    dirs+=($name) 
done

newest=${dirs[0]}
for n in "${dirs[@]}" ; do
    ((n > newest)) && newest=$n
done

cd .backup/mysql_backup/$newest

for file in "*.sql"; do
    prefix="\-\- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: "
    database=$(sed -n "s/$prefix//p" $file)
    printf %"s\n" "Database: $database"
    #mysql -u homestead -psecret --port 33060 --host=127.0.0.1 < $file
done
```

For the sake of debugging, I just printed out the database names with the `Database:`  prefix.
And here's the thing I do not understand.
It just prints out `Database:`  once, and then all the db names.

```
Database: service1
service2
service3
service4
...
```

Would be great to get some help here!
Thanks!

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation. Try to debug, e.g. `set -x` after the shebang, that said the glob `*` does not expand in quotes.

Comment: Also `sh != bash`

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and specifically **5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time**

Comment: Thanks for the link @Jetchisel!
Helped me much! Also to understand why the mistakes I did, were wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here (with comments):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
path=".backup/mysql_backup"

# list newest:
newest="$(find "${path}/" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d|sort -n|tail -1)"

#get all files in that folder:
files="$(find "${newest}" -name "*.sql")"

#loop through the files:
while read -r file;do
    dbname="${file##*/}"
    dbname="${dbname%-*}"
    echo "DEBUG: filename ${file}, dbname ${dbname}"
    echo "mysql -u homestead -psecret --port 33060 --host=127.0.0.1 $dbname < $file"
done <<< "$files"
```

of course you can remove the `echo` at the line which does the import..

> Note: your dbname should NOT contain `-` as that's the delimiter you use to separate the dbname and timestamp in your sql files.. if you use dash `-` in the dbname, then this script should be slightly modified... or in that case you would want to separate dbname and timestamp with a different delimiter, which is not in the dbname.

Comment: Your dedication to answer is great. Though your script does some bad or discouraged things, such as: processing the output of `ls`,  `read` without `-r` not adding double quotes around variable expansions. Checking you script with shellcheck is always good. Answer with bad practice teaches and propagates those.

Comment: answer improved

Comment: Other suggestion, since this is bash, `files` should be an array of filenames rather than a list, e.g. `file=($(find "${newest}" -name "*.sql"))` and then you can redirect with `<<< ${files[@]}` -- helps avoid issues with odd characters in filenames. @Léa Gris covered the most salient points.

Comment: Thank you very much! At first, the link shellcheck.net helped a lot for what was wrong.

```Line 17:
for file in "*.sql"; do
            ^-- SC2066 (error): Since you double quoted this, it will not word split, and the loop will only run once.```
 

and your changes to the script help me understand a solution that works!
Many thanks!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin at least read the output of `find` using `mapfile -d '' files < <(find "${newest}" -name "*.sql" -print0)` expanding a command output in an arry is bad.

Comment: @LéaGris agreed, word-splitting or names with embedded newlines will cause problems with the array filled from the command substitution. `mapfile` (a/k/a `readarray`) is the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method to do this using standard POSIX shell grammar:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

backup_path=".backup/mysql_backup"

# Iterates the directories inside the backup
for newest_dir in "$backup_path/"*"/"; do :; done
# At this point, newest_dir is always the last match
# which is always the latest since globbing is always ordered

# Globbing returns the pattern itself when there is no match
if [ "$newest_dir" = "$backup_path/*/" ]; then
  printf '%s contains no backup directory!\n' "$backup_path" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Iterates the sql files inside the newest backup directory
for file_name in "$newest_dir"*.sql; do

    # Trims-out the leading directory path from the file name
    base_name="${file_name##*/}"

    # Trims out the trailing - anything .sql
    db_name="${base_name%-*.sql}"

    printf  'DEBUG: filename: %s, dbname: %s\n' "$file_name" "$db_name"

    # It is bad practice to insert credentials in code
    # So prefer those in environment variables.
    # Restores database from its backup (uncomment next line if DEBUG ok)
    #mysql -u "$DB_USER" -p"$DB_PASSWORD" --port 33060 --host=127.0.0.1 "$db_name" < "$file_name"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and solution! Not putting the `*` in double quotes, fixed my issue. shellcheck.net helped me figure that out! :)